# How can I divide page into parts in NativeScript app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating app with NativeScript for the first time and I would like to divide screen to 2 parts (one with white background and rounded cornes). If I would create a HTML webpage I would use  and Flexbox.

In my NativeScript Angular app I did it like that:

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">

    <Label height="200px" >
    </Label>

    <Label height="1000px" backgroundColor="white" style="border-radius: 80px 80px 0px 0px;"> 

            <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-active" id="button" text="Tap me!"></Button>


    </Label>


</FlexboxLayout>
```

And it looks ok but nothing appear on this Label. How should I divide my app page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just looks like you aren't using the tags for the right purpose. I think you would want something like this based on the code sample provided.

```
<GridLayout rows="200 *" columns="*">
 <Label />
 <GridLayout row="1" backgroundColor="white" rows="*" columns="*" style="border-radius: 80 80 0 0">
    <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-active" id="button" text="Tap me" />
  </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Labels can only be used with FormattedString and Span tags inside like so.

```
<Label>
   <FormattedString>
        <Span>Some text</Span>
        <Span style="color: blue"> with partial style</Span>
   </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

GridLayout will be your best friend in Nativescript and is far more performant than the FlexboxLayout so use it where you can.

Comment: also using device independant pixels is probably a smarter choice. Nativescript uses this unit by default so removing the `px` will do the trick.

Comment: It is not working exacly how I would like - background of GridLayout is not white but transparent (rounded corners have a 1 pixel outline).

Comment: All you need to fix those issues is more css.